# How to change product enable checkbox to keep disabled by default Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, adminhtml, ui

How do you change the Magento 2 product `Enable` button to `Disabled` by default? My code

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){

  if(typeof inputs[i].getAttribute === 'function' && inputs[i].getAttribute('namw') === 'product[status]'){

    inputs[i].checked = false;

    break;

  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what you have tried in code, then it'll be easy to solve.

Comment: you need this while creating new product?

Comment: S I need while creating new products.. I added style which works fine but js is not working but no error in console.

Comment: I added my code above